# Fixing "str" object is not callable when using set() function Python 3.6.4

Tags: python, scripting, python-3.6

I'm writing some code that is trying to remove duplicates in a string of characters and numbers. I was going to use the `set()` function to remove duplicate characters but it throws an error. I tried reworking things but nothing seemed to fix the issue. In this block of code I'm generating a 10 character long string, then after completing that, running the string through the `set()` function.

```
while(list<=10):
    spacer=random.choice(charlist)
    final=str(final)+str(spacer)
    list+=1
    print(final)

set(final)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 45, in <module>
    set(final)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: In python 2.7 this works `>>> set('aaaabbbb') set(['a', 'b'])` and in 3.7 it works as well `>>> set('aaabbb') {'a', 'b'}`

Comment: You probably overwrote `set` somewhere else in your code. `set = "foobar" # break stuff`. Please show a [mcve]--thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do it as

```py
l=1
import random
final = ''
charlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
while(l<=10):
    spacer=random.choice(charlist)
    final=str(final)+str(spacer)
    l+=1
    print(final)
    set(final)

print(set(final))
```

#### NOTE

Do not use keywords as variables
`list` you had used earlier